# Compare repair quotes

Tags: toyota, power-steering, repair, camry, motor-mounts

My car: Toyota Camry 1994 LE, 4 cyl, 4 door sedan, automatic 127000 miles.

It failed the MD state inspection and following repairs are required.

1. Power steering belt.
2. Power steering pump leak.
3. Power steering pressure line leak.
4. Power steering supply line from reservoir leak.
5. Left front lower control arm.
6. Driver wiper blade.
7. Motor mount (dogbone)

I have a local FireStone quote of $562.93 for parts and $885.90 for labor. I also visited two other repair shop both names start with MANIK. One gave a full quote of $850 (parts + labor) and another $450 (parts + labor). Another local shop gave me a full estimate of $600-700 (parts + labor).

I am not sure how to decide. My ZIP is 21227.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual things to look at are:

- are they using factory parts, or aftermarket?
- what type of warranty are they offering?
- what qualifications or experience do their mechanics have?

These can make a great deal of difference.

Personally, I always go with factory parts, and factory trained mechanics - it is more expensive, but the warranty on parts and labour is worth it for me.